# Maven version control configuration

Tags: java, maven, build

I have builds like: **1.0.0-9, 1.0.0-10, 1.0.0-11, 1.0.0-12, etc.**

I've configured my dependency like: 
**[1.0.0,)**

Which means that it should use the latest version from the existing ones (ofc which starts with 1.0.0), but instead of using the 1.0.0-12 it used the 1.0.0-9. I think that it's because the 9 is grater then the 1.

Firstly I would like to force the maven to use truly my latest builds.

I can also have **1.0.0-LOCAL** build (which is a local build on the developer's PC). I would like to force the maven to use the 1.0.0-LOCAL instead any other builds if it's available.

I don't know exactly how I could do these, maybe somehow with the *settings.xml* configuration file which is located on the build machine and on the developer's PC as well.

If I would have a any other way to do this please let me know.

Have a good day,
      Arnold Robert Turdean

Update:
It turned out that the [Maven Version Range - downloads all the available versions not just the latest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261222/maven-version-range-downloads-all-the-available-versions-not-just-the-latest-o) was the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which maven version do you use? From Maven point of view all of those given versions are releases? The question is if it wouldn't be better to use a SNAPSHOT version instead?

Furthermore to check if the ordering of your artifacts is correct or work like you expect this can be checked by using this:

```
java -jar apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar 1.0.0-12 1.0.0-9
```

Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:

```
1. 1.0.0-12 == 1-12
   1.0.0-12 > 1.0.0-9
2. 1.0.0-9 == 1-9
```

which shows correctly that `1.0.0-12` is greater than `1.0.0-9`. So the question is also if you are using a repository manager etc. ? Do you do only a `mvn install` ?

What I don't understand is your statement about `1.0.0-LOCAL' ?

Apart from that I would suggest to prevent using of version ranges cause they make you build non reproducible.

Comment: Is there a reasonable complete and recent document explaining the ordering of version numbers? Until today I thought that only the first 3 numbers (major.minor.bugfix) are semantically ordered and the rest is ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Starting with Maven 3 it has been changed. See https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html furthermore http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/02/04/apache-maven-how-version-comparison-works/ But this hint reminds me to integrate that into the official Maven site...

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to figure out that not the version number was the problem but another maven behavior ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261222/maven-version-range-downloads-all-the-available-versions-not-just-the-latest-o )

Comment: about what behaviour are you talking about?

Answer (score -1):

In maven, dependency hierarchy is so important. Make sure that you don't have other dependencies which added before, into other pom's.

(In hierarchy, maven cares latest dependency.). Dependency 1.0.0-LOCAL must be the latest one.

I suggest to you, while the local developing time use generic -SNAPSHOT, use numbers when you start packaging .

Comment: Maven does not care about the latest dependency (depends how your version range looks like if you use them) it will select the nearest dependency and that version will be taken...in particular if you think about a dependency tree with more than one level...